# Javascript .Append() and Dynamic Hidden Fields?

Tags: php, javascript, html, textbox, append

I want to create something where you enter text into a text box, and when you press enter or a button it changes a section of words below to match what you entered into the text box... i have heard it has something to do with the stuff in the title but have not been able to find anything close to what i need to do with it, and all the tutorials i could find didn't make sense and still didn't solve my problem even if it did make sense... Can anyone help me in terms of giving me a good link or showing me sample code that is like this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yea just some code on how .Append() works and the hidden fields, but i haven't been able to "put them together"

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're trying to do -- can you show us some sample input/output, and what you have tried (preferably on jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divid").append($("<div />").text($("#inputid").val()));
```

Comment: inputid is the id of your textbox -- replace to suit.  divid is the id of the dom element you want to put the results into -- replace to suit.  Include jQuery in the page, and rig this to the button's click event, and you'll be golden.